# How to pass a macro as the argument to \selectlanguage

Tags: macros, babel, expansion

The following mwe throws the error `You haven't defined the language lang yet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\newcommand{\lang}{american}
\selectlanguage{\lang}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

I can see that `\lang` is not being expanded properly inside `\selectlanguage`, but why does this happen and how do I fix it?

I also tried putting a space before `\lang`, in which case it does get expanded, but Babel now does not recognize the language because of the space.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The definition of `\selectlanguage` is equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\selectlanguage}[1]{%
  \bbl@push@language
  \aftergroup\bbl@pop@language
  \bbl@set@language{#1}%
}
```

where `\bbl@push@language` and `\bbl@pop@language` are maintenance macros to do and undo the language specific adjustments. Now, let's look at the important macro, which is defined by something equivalent to

```
\newcommand\bbl@set@language[1]{%
  \edef\languagename{%
    \ifnum\escapechar=\expandafter`\string#1%
      \@empty
    \else
      \string#1\@empty
    \fi
  }%
  \select@language{\languagename}
  [...]
}
```

where I omit the rest, which is inessential. The macro `\select@language` will expand its argument before doing anything else.

The code makes the assumption that `\escapechar` is set to its normal value (that is, 92). This complicated approach has historic reasons; in olden times, before LaTeX2e, there were a number of extensions to LaTeX for coping with different languages; for being friendly to the users accustomed to write `\german` whenever they wanted to switch to German, `\selectlanguage` was defined to accept both

```
\selectlanguage{german}
```

and

```
\selectlanguage{\german}
```

Let's see what happens with your `\selectlanguage{\lang}`. LaTeX does

```
\edef\languagename{%
  \ifnum\escapechar=\expandafter`\string\lang%
    \@empty
  \else
    \string#1\@empty
  \fi
}%
```

The conditional `\ifnum` wants to see a number and finds `\escapechar` (a numeric parameter), a relation symbol (`<`, `=` or `>`) and finds `=`, then another number; TeX performs expansion when looking for a number, so it expands `\expandafter`, which triggers the expansion of `\string`. After this expansion, what remains on the input stream is

```
\ifnum\escapechar=`\lang
```

where `\lang` are five tokens, because the macro name `\lang` has been “stringified”. The conditional is true, because `` `\ `` (when `\` has category code 12) is an alternative way to say 92. Thus the “true branch” is followed, which makes `lang\@empty` remain on the input stream and so we get the equivalent of

```
\def\languagename{lang\@empty}
```

The `\@empty` will be get rid of later. This explains your error message.

If you say `\selectlanguage{american}`, instead, the conditional would be false and TeX would follow the “false branch” ending with

```
\def\languagename{american\@empty}
```

which is what's wanted.

What to do? If you want to use such a syntax, define your own version of `\selectlanguage`:

```
\newcommand{\xselectlanguage}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\selectlanguage{#1}}\x
}
```

so you'll even be free to have more complex setups like

```
\newcommand{\lang}{\UKorUS english}
\newif\ifUK % conditional start out false
\newcommand{\UKorUS}{\ifUK UK\else US\fi}
%\UKtrue

[...]

\xselectlanguage{\lang}
```

and you'll get `USenglish` until you uncomment the `\UKtrue` line.

Answer (score 10):

Use `\expandafter` trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\newcommand{\lang}{american}
\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\lang}
\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

**Note:** In `babel` package, `\selectlanguage{\foo}` is equivalent to `\selectlanguage{foo}`. This is a feature by design “for historial reasons”. See the remarks of command `\bbl@set@language` in the document of `babel`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek, american]{babel}
\def\lang#1{\selectlanguage{#1}}
\begin{document}
\lang{american}
Hello!
\lang{greek}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (see the title).

Comment: @pts Sorry I should have expanded on the answer. `\lang{\greek}` or `\lang{\american}` also works.