# Define new argument in LaTeX

Tags: macros

I have tried many times something like the following:

```
\def\variable{English}
```

that can be used in the following way later:

```
\selectlanguage{\variable}
```

I am searching for a generic way to solve such problems (I want to predefine arguments, that can be passed to commands).

A similar issue would be the following: Your want to define a string of arguments `\list` passed to `\printbibliography[\list]`.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me, as I was not able to solve that issue with Google.

Comment: For the first problem, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136659/how-to-pass-a-macro-as-the-argument-to-selectlanguage For the second problem, `\list` is a very bad name. Could you show an example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that variable to define?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I am going to give the answer to my question myself:

The trick, as pointed out in the link provided by egreg is to use `\expandafter`:

In the first case:

```
\def\Language{english}
\expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\Language}
```

In the second case:

```
\def\arg{prenote=note}
\expandafter\printbibliography\expandafter[\arg]
```

(of course given you have defined "note" using for example `\defbibnote{note}{testnote}`).

Another use case to further demonstrate applications could be `\includegraphics`:

```
    \def\options{height=3em}
    \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\options]{pathtopicture}
```

Thank you egreg for the helpful link!